# Python 3 Tkinter: NameError with Entry widget: name 'Entry' is not defined

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, nameerror, tkinter-entry

I am writing a GUI on Python 3 using Tkinter, but every time I use Entry(), I get a name error.

I tried a more simpler version of the code, (which is written below), but it still caused a NameError:

```
import tkinter
top = tkinter.Tk()

e = Entry(top)
e.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/gui.py", line 4, in <module>
    e = Entry()
NameError: name 'Entry' is not defined
```

I only recently started coding again, so the answer is probably something extremely simple that I didn't realise was wrong with the code, but thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't import it. Change your code to:

```
e = tkinter.Entry(top)
```

Or import it explicitly:

```
from tkinter import Entry
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't import `Entry` to the local namespace, so you'll need to access it from the module, which you did import:

```
e = tkinter.Entry(top)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you imported the tkinter module, every tkinter action needs to start with tkinter.[function name].

You could also just add:

```
from tkinter import [function name]
```

To import multiple functions you seperate them with a comma.

If you use a lot of functions, it is best to import every function, with

```
from tkinter import *
```

Comment: Your terminology isn't quite correct. The OP didn't import "the tkinter function", but rather they imported the tkinter _module_. Also, while it's true you can import functions (`[function name]`) in the case of tkinter what mostly gets imported are classes. Finally, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) explicitly discourages a wildcard import (eg: `from tkinter import *`) so it's not correct to say "it is best to import every function with `from tkinter import *`".

Comment: @BryanOakley no it's for if you use like 10 functions